# Get chart area bounds in C#

Tags: c#, charts

Just to explain what I'm doing, I draw two selectors on a chart, and the part that will not be selected should appear under that blue rectangle. The part that will be selected will appear in the white area, between the two selectors. The figure below shows only the left selector.

Now, what I'm trying to do is to draw a rectangle inside a chart that always remain inside the plotting area, even when the windows is resized.

To get the top, left and bottom bounds, to draw the rectangle as shown in the figure below, I do the following:

```
(...)
int top = (int)(Chart.Height * 0.07);
int bottom = (int)(Chart.Height - 1.83 * top);
int left = (int)(0.083 * Chart.Width);
Brush b = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(128, Color.Blue));
e.Graphics.FillRectangle(b, left, top, marker1.X - left, bottom - top);
(...)
```

But that's far from perfect, and it isn't drawn in the right place when the window is resized. I want the blue rectangle to always be bound on the top, left and bottom by the plotting area grid. Is that possible?

[image: Chart]

Comment: What charting control are you using?

Comment: @DominiqueJacquel I'm using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart.

Comment: @PragneshPatel Yes. System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to use `StripLine` to achieve this.
Look into the [Stripline Class Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.stripline.aspx).
Also I recommend downloading the [Charting Samples](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart) which are a great help to understand the various features.

```
StripLine stripLine = new StripLine();    
stripLine.Interval = 0;       // Set Strip lines interval to 0 for non periodic stuff
stripLine.StripWidth = 10;    // the width of the highlighted area
stripline.IntervalOffset = 2; // the starting X coord of the highlighted area
// pick you color etc ... before adding the stripline to the axis
chart.ChartAreas["Default"].AxisX.StripLines.Add( stripLine );
```

This assumes you are wanting something that is not what `Cursor` already does (see [CursorX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chartarea.cursorx)), such as letting the user mark up areas of the plot which provides some persistence. Combining the Cursor events with the striplines above would be a good way to do that.

So to highlight the start and end of the cursor you could do this

```
// this would most likely be done through the designer
chartArea1.AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = false;
chartArea1.CursorX.IsUserEnabled = true;
chartArea1.CursorX.IsUserSelectionEnabled = true;
this.chart1.SelectionRangeChanged += new System.EventHandler<System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.CursorEventArgs>(this.chart1_SelectionRangeChanged);
...

private void chart1_SelectionRangeChanged(object sender, CursorEventArgs e)
    {
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.StripLines.Clear();

        StripLine stripLine1 = new StripLine();
        stripLine1.Interval = 0;
        stripLine1.StripWidth = chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.SelectionStart - chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum;
        stripLine1.IntervalOffset = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum;
        // pick you color etc ... before adding the stripline to the axis
        stripLine1.BackColor = Color.Blue;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.StripLines.Add(stripLine1);

        StripLine stripLine2 = new StripLine();
        stripLine2.Interval = 0;
        stripLine2.StripWidth = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum - chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.SelectionEnd;
        stripLine2.IntervalOffset = chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.SelectionEnd;
        // pick you color etc ... before adding the stripline to the axis
        stripLine2.BackColor = Color.Blue;
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.StripLines.Add(stripLine2);
    }
```

Somehow I suspect you may not have discovered the cursor yet, and doing so will make all this irrelevant. But anyway, the above code will do what you described.

Comment: It took me a while to answer this, because I wanted to try your suggestion before I posted something in here. While it does what I wanted to do graphically, it's not exactly what I looked for. What I want to do is mark up the area from the start of the graph up to the first selector, then the area from the second selector up to the end of the graph. Do you see a way of doing this?

Comment: Thank you! I think this will do the job. And yes, I know about the cursor, but what I'm trying to do is different. The cursor allows me to select an area, then if I want to change the area range, I have to select again. I want two markers (which isn't available in the Chart component, AFAIK) through which I can select the start or the end of the range independently. I can adapt what you suggested here to my case, and it works.